# How to create tailable cursor in MongoDB shell?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to create an endless processing loop for capped collection directly in MongoDB, but I can't find how I can get tailabale cursor in MongoDB shell. It's possible in Python with *tailable* option in *Collection.find()* though..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the option after find() using addOption():

`db.coll.find().addOption(2) // probably want to use 2(tailable) + 32(await_data)`

See all the options here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Wire+Protocol#MongoWireProtocol-OPQUERY

You will want to put this in a loop as even tailable cursors (w/await_data) return no results sometimes.