# Server side loop in mongodb to poll queue

Tags: mongodb

I'd like top use MongoDB to handle my queue (instead of AWS SQS I use right now) and I'm going to follow http://www.mattinsler.com/why-and-how-i-replaced-amazon-sqs-with-mongodb/

In both cases (sqs and mongodb) I need a process with a while(true) that polls the queue. In my current configuration (.Net on the cloud) I have to pay for an additional worker role on Azure.

The idea/question is: would it be possible to install a simple js script server side on mongodb that while(true) polls queue (->check for new doc in the db) and fire an http post if found?

Are infinite loop as server side js on mongodb "allowed"? Any comments? Bonus? Malus?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using tailable cursor on capped collection.
It has driver support in most languages :

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tailable+Cursors

( it works like tail -f done on a file, here tailing is done on a collection )

You can periodically restart your script, and get the data tailed for some interval.
Also see : [How to create tailable cursor in MongoDB shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528631/how-to-create-tailable-cursor-in-mongodb-shell)

Comment: Thanks DhruvPathak I read both the links but I still have a doubt. The bonus to use tailable cursor is that if there's nothing to read it blocks for a while instead of returning empty, right? But the timeout is 4 seconds so this means that at the end of the story I have to poll at least every 4 seconds right? The question is, how can I write a while(true) loop in server side js? It's just a matter of:
db.system.js.save( { _id : "foo" , value : function( x , y ){ while(true) { pause(4000); dosomething(x,y); } } } );