# mongoDB + nodeJS: can't keep a stream cursor open

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockjs

For a log viewer, I have to write the updates in a mongoDB collection on a sockJS socket.

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372626/how-to-stream-mongodb-query-results-with-nodejs), I'm using the stream cursor of the native nodeJS driver to do so, but it only works for the content present in the collection when I create the stream. None of the further updates are written.

Here is my code:

```
var server = new mongodb.Server(config.db_host, config.db_port, {});
var DB = new mongodb.Db('myLogs', server, {w:0}).open(function (error, database) {
    if (error) throw error;
    db.logs = database.collection('logs');
});

var stream = db.logs.find({user: sID}, {sort: [['_id', 'asc']]}).stream();

stream.on('error', function (err) {
    socket.write(JSON.stringify({'action': 'log','param': 'log db streaming error'}));
});
stream.on('data', function (doc) {
    socket.write(JSON.stringify({'action': 'log','param': doc.log}));
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Can this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a capped collection, you can use the [TailableCursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/), which does what you want. A standard [CursorStream](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursorstream.html?highlight=stream#CursorStream) returns only the results that matched at the time of the call to `find` (as you've seen).

There isn't a wealth of info for doing this in Node.JS though. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528631/how-to-create-tailable-cursor-in-mongodb-shell)'s a pointer in the right direction.

While I haven't tested this code, it should be something like below. The key is using a capped collection and setting the `tailable` and `awaitdata` option to `true`.

```
var stream = db.logs.find({user: sID}, {
    tailable: true,
    awaitdata: true 
    /* other options */
}).stream();

stream.on('data', function (doc) {
    socket.write(JSON.stringify({'action': 'log','param': doc.log}));
});
```

Comment: I think you'll also want to include the `awaitdata: true` option.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.

I've tried it and made this change, plus changed the collection creation to `db.logs = database.collection('logs', {'capped':true, 'size':10000});`. I had dumped the old collection before to start clean.

But, I get an error telling me that I can only create a tailable cursor of a capped collection. Do I have to do something more to make my collection capped?

Comment: Solved: I had to create the collection through the MongoDB shell command. The nodeJS equivalent function doesn't create it capped. I'll add a small remark to your answer and accept it. Thanks a lot.